# How to view all users' access permissions (security tab) for all shared folders?

Tags: powershell, shared-directory

I have many shared folders in a server. I need to view the users who has access to them using PowerShell but I do not know how to do it as I am new in PowerShell.

Do you have any scripts to do that?

Input: root folder, or server name. Any is ok for me
Output: folder, user

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. If you're entirely unfamiliar with a language please go find a tutorial for it. SO is not a replacement for that.

Comment: if u do not want to help. do not reply is better for yourself

Answer (score 2):

Look into using `Get-ACL`. This gives you the Access Control List for a folder.

Here is more information from Microsoft on ACLs: [Get-Acl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-5.1)